# How i can disable Windows 8 Start menu second monitor?

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors

So i have 1 question.
How i can disable this Start menu Win 8 second monitor?:

[image: http://prntscr.com/4ww0l6]

I use Actual Multiple Monitors default taskbar, and disturb me.

default:

[image: http://prntscr.com/4ww158]

Thank you very much

Comment: Is `Actual Multiple Monitors ` third-party software?  Because the default behavior with 8.1 is the Start Button( and start screen ) only exists on the primary monitor

Answer (score 0):

Kind of didn't understand your question but,

Do you want to disable only start button or taskbar?

If you want to disable taskbar on second monitor, just right click taskbar and untick show taskbar in all monitors.

If you want to disable Start button you could use a third party application named Classic Shell. It's free. Install it and go to settings, tick show all settings, start button, then untick show on all taskbars.